# Rust: Iterator that repeats the first and last element of another Iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

Is there an `Iterator`, either in `std` or a maintained crate, that repeats the first and last element of another `Iterator` given `Item` is `Clone`?

Example:

```
let iter = [1, 2, 3].into_iter();

assert!(iter.repeat_first_and_last().eq([1, 1, 2, 3, 3]));
```

Comment: This seems so niche that I would be quite suprised if there was.

Comment: Fair. Two separate operations would also work, and seems less niche.

Comment: If the iterator only has one element, should that be provided twice or three times?

Comment: Three times. So the count would be the wrapped iterator's count plus two in every case except when the wrapped iterator's count is zero, in which case the count would have to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own.

```
use std::{mem::take, iter::Fuse};

use tap::Tap;

struct Padded<T: Iterator> {
    inner: Fuse<T>,
    repeat_first: bool,
    repeat_last: bool,
    next: Option<T::Item>,
}

impl<T: Iterator> Padded<T>
where
    T::Item: Clone,
{
    fn new(inner: impl IntoIterator<IntoIter = T>) -> Self
    where
        T::Item: Clone,
    {
        let mut inner = inner.into_iter().fuse();
        let next = inner.next();
        
        Self { inner, next, repeat_first: true, repeat_last: true, }
    }
}

impl<T: Iterator> Iterator for Padded<T>
where
    T::Item: Clone,
{
    type Item = T::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.take().tap(|next| {
            if take(&mut self.repeat_first) {
                self.next = next.clone();
            } else {
                self.next = self.inner.next().or_else(|| {
                    next.as_ref().filter(|_| take(&mut self.repeat_last)).cloned()
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    Padded::new([1, 2, 3]).for_each(|n| print!("{n}"));
}
```

Comment: Both solutions need `FusedIterator` the same amount. "Last element of an iterator" is just not well-defined for non-fused iterators.

Comment: You're right, I confused `FusedIterator` with `DoubleEndedIterator`. Will fix my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also roll your own if you want:

```
use std::iter::Fuse;

pub struct FirstLastRepeat<I, T> {
    iter: Fuse<I>,
    head: Option<T>,
    tail: Option<T>,
    stash: Option<T>,
}

impl<I, T> FirstLastRepeat<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    pub fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        let mut iter = iter.fuse();
        let head = iter.next();
        Self {
            iter,
            head,
            tail: None,
            stash: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<I, T> Iterator for FirstLastRepeat<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let v @ Some(_) = self.head.take() {
            self.stash = v.clone();
            return v;
        }
        if let v @ Some(_) = self.tail.take() {
            return v;
        }
        let next = self.stash.take();
        match self.iter.next() {
            v @ Some(_) => self.stash = v,
            None => self.tail = next.clone(),
        }
        next
    }
}

#[test]
fn basic() {
    let iter = [1, 2, 3].into_iter();
    let flr = FirstLastRepeat::new(iter);

    assert!(flr.eq([1, 1, 2, 3, 3]));
}
```

The only weird edge case here is an original iterator with only one element. It's not clear what the right behaviour here is, but `FristLastRepeat` will yield it three times which doesn't seem correct in any case. That could be fixed though.

Comment: Usually, you don't constrain on `FusedIterator`, but rather use `fuse()` and the standard library will optimize fused iterators.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good to know! I've amended the answer to use `fuse`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no method I know of in either `std` or `itertools` for that. You can combine multiple iterator methods to accomplish this, though:

```
use std::iter::repeat;

fn main() {
    let iter = [1, 2, 3, 4].into_iter();
    let len = iter.len();

    let res: Vec<u8> = iter
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, x)| repeat(x).take((i == 0 || i == len - 1).then(|| 2).unwrap_or(1)))
        .flatten()
        .collect();

    assert_eq!(res, vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af42f8acfd05b7158867eaa5c3c3561c)

Note that repeating the last element twice requires us to know the size of the iterator beforehand, so the iterator type must implement [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html), or you have to provide some other means to get the length.